# Height attribute

Tags: html5, css3

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему при указанных `width="600"` и `height="400"` реальные размеры изображения `180x120`?

[Посмотреть вживую](https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery)

Comment: А посмотреть что перекрывает нельзя? https://www.screencast.com/t/f44LXkVdu6vm

Comment: Я просто хотел узнать откуда взялся 180x120?

Comment: Это реальный сайт? Я могу зайти посмотреть лично?

Comment: https://www.w3schools.com/css/tryit.asp?filename=trycss_image_gallery

Answer (score 2):

Как можно увидеть здесь
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Свойства `width` и `height` перекрываются из `div.gallery img` CSS стиля.

Comment: спасибо большое

Comment: @NorayrGhukasyan слева зеленое спасибо ;)